# Why the oldest kernel is marked as recommended in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, linux-kernel, version

In update manager, there is View->"Linux kernels" option.
It contains a list of kernels and as far as I know the freshest builds must be the most optimized and stable.

For example in Linux Mint 17 Qiana, why 3.13.0-24(3.13.9) kernel is marked as recommended, not the newest one (3.13.0-68 on the date of posting this question) of the same branch?

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, the older programs have more *known* bugs, and their risk can be gauged.  It is common to backport selected fixes to stable versions of programs.  Newer releases have more *unknowns*, and their risk cannot be as easily gauged.

Comment: On the other hand, those known bugs are already fixed in newer builds. Accordingly to the development life cycle major and minor changes are made in new branches whereas in old one basically bugs are fixed. That's why it becomes more stable. Am I right? In addition, those known bug list can contain critical bugs including security issues and I can't understand how it can be recommended then.

Comment: Not necessarily (I have never found that to be true).  Interesting bugs surface after use over an extended period of time.